# How can I use the variables from `env` file in my typescript react project?

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

So I have an `API_KEY` which I'm storing in `.env` file, and using javascript template I had no problems accessing `.env` file. But now I'm using a typescript template and I want to know how can I use variables from `.env` file.

It looks like this:

```
API_KEY={myapikey}
API_BASE={api_base}
```

And that's the way I access it in a redux slice:

```
const API_BASE = process.env.API_BASE;
const TMDB_API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
```

And then I fetch data using redux thunk:

```
export const fetchPopular = createAsyncThunk('popular/fetchPopular', async () => {
  const response = await axios.get<MovieResults>(`${API_BASE}movie/popular?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}`);
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data.results;
})
```

But in the end it returns me `undefined`, although when I declared api key and api base directly everything was alright.

Edit:
I had `dot-env` installed and now I imported it in my `index.tsx` using:

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env)
```

And now I have next errors:
[image]

Comment: Prefix them? See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Do you have `dotenv` installed, or a package that depends on it (like `react-dotenv`)? https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @jonrsharpe hi! i prefixed them but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Then please [edit] to give a [mre] that follows the guidance.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i edited my original question and added more details

Comment: That's _not_ following the guidance. You can't run Node-specific modules like fs in a browser environment, so even if you were configuring Webpack and dotenv yourself that wouldn't go in index.tsx.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so i should import `dot-env` in another file? i didn't encounter this so i'm not sure

Comment: If you're using CRA, as "typescript template" implies, this is all set up for you and you need to _follow the documentation_ I've linked. If not, it's going to depend on how your app is set up, and you haven't given nearly enough information about that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i'm sorry for my ignorance, but what info could i provide about my app? you mean how the folders are ordered?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the problem. The first commenter said that I should prefix my variables adding `REACT_APP_` before them and I did it but nothing happened.
Then I read in the documentation he sent that I need to restart the development server after prefixing the variables and it worked.
So after prefixing the variables you need to re-run the server with `npm start`.

Comment: Yes. You don't need additional package to handle .env in React project.
Just prefix the variable with REACT_APP and it will be available via process.env